# Aggregate Total count

Tags: python-3.x, oracle

I want to merge two columns(Sender and Receiver) and get the Transaction Type count.

```
Sender      Receiver  Type  Amount  Date
773787639   777611388   1   300    2/1/2019
773631898   776806843   4   450    8/20/2019
773761571   777019819   6   369    2/11/2019
774295511   777084440   34  1000   1/22/2019
774263079   776816905   45  678    6/27/2019
774386894   777202863   12  2678   2/10/2019
773671537   777545555   14  38934  9/29/2019
774288117   777035194   18  21     4/22/2019
774242382   777132939   21  1275    9/30/2019
774144715   777049859   30  6309    7/4/2019
773911674   776938987   10  3528    5/1/2019
773397863   777548054   15  35892   7/6/2019
776816905   772345091   6   1234    7/7/2019
777035194   775623065   4   453454  7/20/2019
```

I am try to get like this kind of table

```
Sender/Receiver    Type_1    Type_4    Type_12...... Type_45
773787639            3          2         0            0
773631898            1          0         1            2
773397863            2          2         0            0 
772345091            1          1         0            3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a pivot query.  The only twist here is that we need to first take a union of the table to combine the sender/receiver data into a single column.

```
SELECT
    SenderReceiver,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Type_1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Type_2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 3 THEN 1 END) AS Type_3,
    ...
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 45 THEN 1 END) AS Type_45
FROM
(
    SELECT Sender AS SenderReceiver, Type FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Receiver, Type FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY
    SenderReceiver;
```

If you don't want to type out 45 separate `CASE` expressions, you could probably automate it to some degree using Python.

Comment: The "union all" is an **unpivot** operation. Using union all is inefficient - it requires reading the base table twice. Use the UNPIVOT operator, or unpivot the old way (Oracle version <= 10.2) - which is to use a cross join to a table with one column and two rows.

Comment: @mathguy I have almost never used `UNPIVOT` in Oracle, and I can't even debate your comment.  In most versions of SQL, there is no format unpivot operator, and my answer would be the way to go.

Comment: Unpivot using a cross join should work in all versions of SQL, and only requires reading the base table once. (I believe the `unpivot` operator in Oracle does little more than that anyway). That specific part of your answer is probably not the most efficient way to go in any SQL dialect. Did you ever unpivot using a cross join (Cartesian join)? Are you familiar with the technique?

Comment: @mathguy No, I haven't, maybe you should post an answer.  I "get" the inefficiency in my answer, because the union doubles the size of the table, and then forces Oracle to start the query on that intermediate, rather then the original table itself (thus killing any chance of using indices).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  i am Getting more error message on Group By function

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It saying "query block has incorrect number of result columns"

Comment: You are not running the exact code in my answer, which can't have that error.  The error means that the two selects in the union select differing numbers of columns.  In my answer, they both select only two columns.

Comment: `SELECT SENDER_RECEIVER,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN TX_TYPE_ID = '6' THEN 1 END ) AS CX_ACCOUNT_RECHARGE,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN TX_TYPE_ID = '7' THEN 1 END ) AS CX_CASH_WITHDRAWEL 
 
FROM 
(
 SELECT INITIATOR_ALIAS AS SENDER_RECEIVER, TX_TYPE_ID
 FROM E_WALLET.EZ_DM_TRANSACTION_LOG  UNION ALL
 SELECT RECIPIENT_ALIAS
 FROM E_WALLET.EZ_DM_TRANSACTION_LOG 
 )t

GROUP BY 
   SENDER_RECEIVER`

Comment: The second select in the union is _wrong_, and should be this: `SELECT RECIPIENT_ALIAS, TX_TYPE_ID FROM E_WALLET.EZ_DM_TRANSACTION_LOG`

Comment: yeah it is working, but my DB is very large so it take some time to execute, once it excute i will let you know.

Comment: Bro, How to get total Amount under each type ?

Comment: For example, for the first type, use: `SELECT ... SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN Amount END) AS Amount_Type_1`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have small concern, if want to join another table with above table  how can i join that table? (Join key is SenderReceiver)

Comment: @Shulaz That follow-up question does not belong here; you should open a new question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, i opened new question(link is below)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59781841/get-total-count