# Get Total count

Tags: oracle

I want to merge two columns(Sender and Receiver) and get the Transaction Type count then merge another table with using Sender_Receiver primary id.

```
Sender      Receiver  Type  Amount  Date
773787639   777611388   1   300    2/1/2019
773631898   776806843   4   450    8/20/2019
773761571   777019819   6   369    2/11/2019
774295511   777084440   34  1000   1/22/2019
774263079   776816905   45  678    6/27/2019
774386894   777202863   12  2678   2/10/2019
773671537   777545555   14  38934  9/29/2019
774288117   777035194   18  21     4/22/2019
774242382   777132939   21  1275    9/30/2019
774144715   777049859   30  6309    7/4/2019
773911674   776938987   10  3528    5/1/2019
773397863   777548054   15  35892   7/6/2019
776816905   772345091   6   1234    7/7/2019
777035194   775623065   4   453454  7/20/2019
```

Second Table

```
Mobile_number     Age
773787639         34
773787632         23
774288117         65
```

I am try to get like this kind of table

```
Sender/Receiver    Type_1    Type_4    Type_12...... Type_45   Age
773787639            3          2         0            0       23
773631898            1          0         1            2       56
773397863            2          2         0            0       65
772345091            1          1         0            3       32
```

Comment: Is your type can contain a variable value or is it defined (e.g. only 1,4,12, .. 45)?

Comment: @Tejash it is variable value, Total number of count type wise per user

Comment: @Tejash one of the guys answered  this question but i want to merged another table with  Sender/Receiver join key, i attached that link,      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622275/aggregate-total-count/59622312?noredirect=1#comment105675679_59622312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have seen your old question and you just need `inner join` in `sub-query` as following:

> ```
> SELECT
>     SenderReceiver,
>     COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Type_1,
>     COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Type_2,
>     COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 3 THEN 1 END) AS Type_3,
>     ...
>     COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 45 THEN 1 END) AS Type_45,
>     Age -- changes here
> FROM
> (   SELECT sr.SenderReceiver, sr.Type, st.Age from -- changes here
>     (SELECT Sender AS SenderReceiver, Type FROM yourTable
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT Receiver, Type FROM yourTable) sr
>     join <second_table> st on st.Mobile_number = sr.SenderReceiver -- changes here
> ) t
> GROUP BY
>     SenderReceiver,
>     Age; -- changes here
> ```

Changes done in your previous query are marked with comments `-- changes here`.

Please replace the name of the `<second_table>` with the original name of the table.

Cheers!!

Comment: if I want to get month-wise Tx type count(eg: Type_1_Jan19,Type_1_feb19,Type_2_Jan18......), how can I get bro?

Comment: you need to use `COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 1 AND TRUNC("DATE",'MONTH') = DATE '2019-01-01' THEN 1 END) AS TYPE_1_JAN19` and so on for other columns

Comment: Thank you @Tejash it is working, but if I want to get Tx_type wise monthly count last two years. how can I get?

Comment: Hi @Tejash, is there any way to convert the "Tx_Type" column to column-wise without defining one by one because I don't what are the types are in the table( Type1, Type2,....Type_x,Type_y)?